# How to access value of a jenkins groovy variable in shell script for loop

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins-groovy

When i am passing value of a variable declared in jenkins Groovy script its value is not retained in for loop which is running on a remote server. Strange thing is i am able to access the same value outside the for loop.

Here is the sample code i am trying to use

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def config
def COMMANDS_TO_CHECK='curl grep hello awk tr mkdir bc'
pipeline {

    agent {
        label "master"
    }

    stages {
            stage ('Validation of commands') {         
            steps {
                script {
                    sh """
                    #!/bin/bash
                    /usr/bin/sshpass -p passwrd ssh user@host << EOF
                    hostname

                      echo $COMMANDS_TO_CHECK ---> This is printed
                          for CURRENT_COMMAND in \$COMMANDS_TO_CHECK
                        do
                        echo ${CURRENT_COMMAND}  ---> Why This is not printed?
                        echo \${CURRENT_COMMAND} ----> Why This is not printed?
                        done
                        hostname
EOF
                        exit

"""

}
}
}
}
}
```

Output

```
[workspace@3] Running shell script
+ /usr/bin/sshpass -p passwrd ssh user@host
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
illinsduck01
curl grep hello awk tr mkdir bc
illinsduck01
+ exit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap sh in """ ... """ as below

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def config
pipeline {
agent {
    label "master"
}
stages {
    stage ('Validation of commands') {         
        steps {
            script {
            sh """#!/bin/sh
            /usr/bin/sshpass -p password ssh username@hostname << EOF
            COMMANDS_TO_CHECK="curl grep hello awk tr mkdir bc"


            hostname

            echo \$COMMANDS_TO_CHECK

            for CURRENT_COMMAND in \$COMMANDS_TO_CHECK
            do
            echo \$CURRENT_COMMAND
            which \$CURRENT_COMMAND
            status=\$?

            if [ \${status} -eq 0 ]
            then
               echo  \${CURRENT_COMMAND} command is OK
            else
               echo "Failed to find the \${CURRENT_COMMAND} command"
            fi
            done
            hostname
            EOF

            exit    
           """
           }
         }
       }
     }
  }
```

Comment: I tried that but it did not work. i am having issue in declaring COMMANDS_TO_CHECK="curl grep hello awk tr mkdir bc" inside sh i guess. when i simply declare it and try to echo value of COMMANDS_TO_CHECK it shows nothing